# Is there a group isomorphism between finite (abelian) groups where one can prove that the inverse has no analytically closed form?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elliptic-curves, group-isomorphism, cryptography

In the case of the discrete logarithm (with the application of elliptic curve cryptography that maps a finite cyclic group to the cyclic subgroup of the elliptic curve defined by the generator point) we know that the map is a group isomorphism. However so far no one was able to provide an easy to compute inverse map.

Though I am pessimistic that I get a positive reply I was wondering if examples are known where we can proof that it is impossible to analytically construct an easy to compute inverse map?

Comment: hi Rene. can you explain what you mean by "analytically closed" and "easy to compute"?

Comment: For any fixed elliptic curve, the inverse is easy to compute; just find the generator.  It's finding an algorithm that works for any elliptic curve that's tricky.  **tl;dr:** you really want two _families_ of finite abelian groups such that (1) corresponding groups are isomorphic but (2) there is no algorithm constructing an isomorphism in a reasonable time (say, polynomial in the size of those groups).